# Figuring out maximum memory requirement for R function

Tags: r, memory, profiling

How can I find the maximum memory requirement for an R function? I am trying to improve the resource requirements for a function, but am running into difficulty figuring out the maximum memory footprint.

It appears that `gc()` reports the maximum memory used, but this maximum is subject to issues of when gc is run during the function. The best I have been able to do is set a maximum memory with `ulimit -v` prior to starting R and running the script, and then decreasing that limit until the script fails. This is a rather slow, iterative process.

Is there a way to figure out the resource requirements in a single R session?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the documentation for [profiling R code for memory use](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Profiling-R-code-for-memory-use). The example in the help file for `Rprofmem()` is also helpful.

First call `Rprofmem()` with a file for the output and a lower limit for when to write the stack trace:

```
Rprofmem("Rprofmem.out", threshold = 1000)
```

Then run some code:

```
<your function>
```

Then turn off profiling and look at the file

```
Rprofmem(NULL)
noquote(readLines("Rprofmem.out", n = <some integer>))
```

The largest are at the top.